# MDI Parent Menu and Child Menu

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menu-items

I am using VB.Net on Winforms Development developing an MDI application.

In my Parent form, I have a menu strip.  In my child forms, I also have a menu strip attached to each form, which invokes a different set of command when accessed.  Is it possible then that in an MDI form, the child form which is currently active be the menu that would display in the parent form?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy.  Just add a MenuStrip to the parent but leave it empty.  The built-in support for menu merging ensures that the active child's menu appears in the empty parent strip.